# Why does it keep telling me it cannot find symbol?

Tags: java

The other Chapter 2 example files are working fine. I can't figure out why this particular class is having these problems - where I'm getting errors are labeled in comments.

```
package chapter2;

public class DataTypeConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x;
        int pies = 10; //error: not a statement
        x = y; //error: cannot find symbol: variable y

        int pies = 10, people = 4;
        double piesPerPerson;
        piesPerPerson = pies / people;
        piesPerPerson = (double) pies / people;

        final double INTEREST_RATE = 0.069; //Note that the variable name does not have
        amount = balance * 0.069; //error: cannot find symbol: variable: amount 
        amount = balance * INTEREST_RATE;
    }
}
```

My goal is to use this code as a stand alone Java file, so I don't know why it's complaining so much. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can see you have not declared `amount` anywhere or `y`

Comment: or y or balance. you must declare them before using them

Comment: There is nothing special about your `INTEREST_RATE`; it is just a variable which happens to be `final`. Note that by convention, uppercase plus underscores are used for `static` variables.

Comment: Also, you're declaring `pies` twice.

Comment: as @Jason said, there is no declaration for those variables,. you must declare them before using them,.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare your variables before using them. Add this line at the top:

```
double y, amount, balance;
```

Comment: +1 for amount and balance...not sure about y though, don't know what it's suppose to be...

Answer (score 1):

- `y` is not declared or initialized before use. eg: `int y = 0;` (note, `y` is supposed to be an `int`, due to the exercise demonstrating narrowing/widening concepts)
- `pies` is declared twice, lines 30 and 41. Remove line 30.
- `amount` is not declared . eg: `double amount = balance * 0.069;`
- `balance` is not declared or initialized before use, eg: `double balance = 10.0;` (must be done
  before attempting to use it with `amount` in line 59)

I think the key you need to remember at this stage is that before you can use a variable for the first time, it must be declared as a specific data type. eg: `int`, `double`, `String`, etc.  A good practice, particularly as a student (which I am), is to declare all of your variables at the beginning of the code block (class/method/function, etc) in which they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `y` is suppose to be equal, but you've not decalred it anywhere, so Java doesn't know anything about it...

You could try something like...

```
double x, y, amount, balance; // Might as weel add amount and balance cause they'll cause you errors now...
int pies = 10;//error: not a statement
x = y; // But this is garbage as y's value is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate variable declaration:

```
 int pies = 10;
```

and

```
int pies = 10, people = 4;
```